# How to insert shipment tracking code via Rest API Python wrapper and WooCommerce Shipment Tracking plug-in

Tags: python, woocommerce

**Set-up**

I'm using the official [WooCommerce Shipment Tracking](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/shipment-tracking/) plug-in to match orders with tracking codes.

I'm also using Python and the WooCommerce Rest API to do as much as possible via scripts.

---

**Issue**

The Shipment Tracking plug-in should work with the REST API, see: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/shipment-tracking/#section-8.

However, the explanation stated on the documentation page does not contain a Python example.

I'm not sure how to insert the tracking number and tracking provider via Python and the WooCommerce REST API in the WooCommerce back-end.

---

**Code**

Using,

```
data = {
        'tracking_number': tracking_number,
        'tracking_provider': tracking_provider,
        'date_shipped': datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        }
```

I have tried,

- `wcapi.post('orders/' + order_id + '/shipment-trackings', data).json()`
- `wcapi.put('orders/' + order_id + '/shipment-trackings', data).json()`
- `wcapi.post('orders/' + order_id, data).json()`
- `wcapi.put('orders/' + order_id, data).json()`

but all yield a `404` error.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting a 404 you may be hitting a version of the API that doesn't support shipment tracking: looking at the docs it says **Version 1.5+ support the REST API**. When you create `wcapi` what version did you point to? Should look something like (from the docs at https://pypi.org/project/WooCommerce/):

```
wcapi = API(
    url="http://example.com",
    consumer_key="ck_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    consumer_secret="cs_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    version="wc/v3"
)
```

Comment: Hi Femi, thank you for thinking with me. Sadly, that is the version I'm using.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is that the shipment tracking plugin isn't installed? That would give you a 404.